# Trouble printing the value of a Long division and multiplication

Tags: java, math, integer, long-integer

I have trouble figuring out why a simple division like this one always returns 0.

```
System.out.println(4091365376L / 4091495462L * 100L);
```

I suffixed all numbers with Ls so they're treated as Longs. I keep getting a zero.

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of 4091365376L to 4091495462L. My values are Longs but I'm just looking for a simple Integer value.

Comment: Its been a while in Java, but I think you need to use the % character to return the "mod".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a victim of integer rounding (actually: truncation). Try this:

```
System.out.println(4091365376L * 100L / 4091495462L);
```

Prints `99`. Or cast to `double` implicitly:

```
System.out.println(100.0 * 4091365376L / 4091495462L);
```

Giving `99.99682057572328`. Your problem is that `4091495462L` is slightly bigger than `4091365376L` so when diving them, the result is truncated to `0` (try `3 / 4`, if you are not convinced). and `0` times `100` is...

Answer (score 4):

```
4091365376L / 4091495462L * 100L
\_______________________/       |
      0.99... = 0               |
      \_________________________/
                    0
```

You could express it like

```
100 * 4091365376L / 4091495462L
```

then it would become

```
100 * 4091365376L / 4091495462L
\_______________/              |
  409136537600L                |
  \____________________________/
          99.99... = 99
```

Comment: I like ASCII diagrams. It really makes it easy in these cases. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Order is important, as is type.  The output of a long divided by a long is a long.  The result of the division you're performing is 0, and 0 * 100 == 0.  You would be much better off using something like this:

```
System.out.println((long) (4091365376.0 / 4091495462.0 * 100));
```

Answer (score -1):

In integer math:

```
4091365376 / 4091495462 = 0
0 * 100 = 0
```

You're expecting

```
4091365376 / 4091495462 = 0.9999682057572327
0.9999682057572327 * 100 = 99.99682057572327
```

but you can't do that with integers (or long integers).  Use doubles if you want a double value.